# Using ApolloClient with node.js. "fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed"

Tags: node.js, polyfills, apollo-client

I am attempting to use an Apollo Client on a node.js server to interface with another GraphQL API using the following code:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'

import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'
import { API_URL } from '...'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createHttpLink({
    uri: API_URL,
    fetch: fetch,
  }),
})
```

Which yields the following error:

```
module initialization error: Error
fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed, to fix pass a fetch for
your environment like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch.

For example:
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';

const link = createHttpLink({ uri: '/graphql', fetch: fetch });
at Object.checkFetcher (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-link-http-common/lib/bundle.umd.js:78:19)
at createHttpLink (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-link-http/lib/bundle.umd.js:32:30)
at new HttpLink (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-link-http/lib/bundle.umd.js:203:38)
at new DefaultClient (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-boost/lib/index.js:80:24)
```

I understand that the Apollo Client by default is expecting to be run in a browser context where a `fetch` method will be available, and that in a node.js I need to polyfill or otherwise provide a `fetch` method, but I having trouble figuring out exactly how to do this.

Following the example code at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/#apollo-client it appears that I should be able to pass this information in using the `link` option, and reading the `apollo-boost` source code seems to suggest that you can pass this information in using `fetcherOptions`, but neither of these solutions seem to work.

Can anyone provide some example code for initializing an Apollo Client in node.js with a fetcher?

For reference here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "API-Service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.6",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.4",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "json-rules-engine": "^2.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.1.2",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions below, none of them works
I would always get teh error `Invariant Violation: 1`... (or that self is undefined when using whatwg-fetch)...
Is there another solution?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It turns out that the `ApolloClient` provided by the `apollo-boost` library does not accept a `link` option. Switching to use the vanilla `apollo-client` allows you to specify your fetching mechanism.

Although `apollo-boost` and `apollo-client` both export an `ApolloClient` in the docs, they take wildly different options.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'

import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'
import { API_URL } from '...'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createHttpLink({
    uri: API_URL,
    fetch: fetch,
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

Comment: does it mean that we cannot use apollo-boost?

Comment: Still not working, with this I get `undefined is not an object`.

Answer (score 44):

If you still want to use Apollo Boost in Node.js but need to polyfill the native fetch API of the browser, try out [cross-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch). I used it for my minimal example over [here](https://github.com/the-road-to-graphql/node-apollo-boost-github-graphql-api/blob/master/src/index.js). And that's how it can be used after installing it:

```
import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://api.domain.com/graphql',
});
```

Comment: This worked for me using react native and Jest! Thanks

Comment: this is not working with React and Jest, do we have to make any other changes in jest config or so?

Comment: Still getting `fetch is not globally and no fetcher passed...`

Comment: Solved the exact same error that jest showed to me. +1 :)

Answer (score 25):

You can add `fetch` option directly to the `ApolloClient` from `apollo-boost`. Here is the example code

Ref. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started/#configuration-options

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const client = new ApolloClient({
    fetch: fetch
});
```

Tested with `apollo-boost` version `0.4.3`

Comment: THANK YOU ! I confirmed this also works with `@apollo/react-hooks` 3.1.0 and `apollo-boost` 0.4.4 inside `next`.js 9.0.5. 

Comment: This is exactly the solution that I come up with for Jest as well.

Comment: Thanks, works with next 9.1.4 and apollo-boost 0.4.4, too!

Comment: This works for me as well for the latest version (at this time) of Apollo boost

Comment: Still not working, with this I get `undefined is not an object`.

Answer (score 15):

Try `cross-fetch` without a polyfill in node.

This even works with typescript. 
(conversely, `node-fetch`'s type is incompatible with the standard whatwg fetch spec.)

```js
import fetch from 'cross-fetch'

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "<your-uri>",
  fetch,
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`whatwg-fetch`](https://github.com/github/fetch#installation) polyfill:

```
yarn add whatwg-fetch
```

The installation instructions depend on your usage (e.g Babel, Webpack etc.) and are in the provided link.

In my case I needed the polyfill for my Jest tests so I just put this in my test setup file:

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that exact error, but fortunately I had already included `node-fetch` in my project, so I have imported it and associated it to the Apollo client.:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import {targetServer} from "./apiConstants";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

const client = new ApolloClient({
    fetch: fetch,
    uri: targetServer + '/graphql',
});
```

and in my `package.json` this is what I have:

```
{
  "name": "learn-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.5",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "graphql": "^15.1.0",
    "next": "9.3.5",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    ...
  }
}
```