# ApolloClient is not a constructor (apollo-client with nodejs)

Tags: node.js, graphql

I don't have any UI framework. Just a simple Nodejs script where I need to query a GraphQL.

Codes:

```
const ApolloClient = require('apollo-client')
const client = new ApolloClient()
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: ApolloClient is not a constructor
```

Package.json:

```
{
  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-client": "^2.4.13",
    "graphql": "^14.1.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1"
  },
}
```

Node: `v8.9.4`

I googled a while people have this issue mainly because `ApolloClient is no longer in react-apollo. You have to import it from 'apollo-client'`

And I'm importing from `apollo-client` as `const ApolloClient = require('apollo-client')`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using `require`, you can import it like this:

```
const ApolloClient = require('apollo-client').default
```

or like this

```
const { ApolloClient } = require('apollo-client')
```

Otherwise, you're importing the entire module, which itself is not a constructor.

Answer (score 7):

For people who like me using Node `require` and just want to get it working.

Packages:

`npm install graphql apollo-client apollo-cache-inmemory apollo-link-http node-fetch --save`

Codes:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const { createHttpLink } = require('apollo-link-http')
const { InMemoryCache } = require('apollo-cache-inmemory')
const { ApolloClient } = require('apollo-client')
const gql = require('graphql-tag')

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
  fetch: fetch
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

const query = gql`
  query {
    viewer {
      login
    }
  }
`

client.query({
  query
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
  done()
})
```

The response is error as you need to add `Authorization: bearer YOURTOKEN` to request header but that's another thing.

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50689652/10769364)

Answer (score 4):

I have a related issue, although using `node --experimental-modules`, not CommonJS. I'm using `apollo-client` version `2.6.x` and node version `12.x` so this might change.

Here's how I tried to import it:

```
import { default as ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';

const client = new ApolloClient();
```

The reason why it doesn't work is that `--experimental-modules` still imports CommonJS version of a given module even though `package.json` has a `"module"` field pointing to ESM entry point. It happens because EcmaScript Modules support in Node 12+ relies on either `"type"` field in `package.json` or "Michael Jackson script" (`.mjs`) file extension. And using named import with CommonJS is not supported: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_compatibility_with_commonjs_only_versions_of_node_js

So, how to fix? There are two approaches:

1. Ask apollo client authors to publish ESM package with `"type": "module"` field in `package.json`
2. Use workarounds in the source code
3. Use `esm`

Here's a workaround:

```
import apolloClient from 'apollo-client';
const { ApolloClient } = apolloClient;
```

Bonus: full example

```
import nodeFetch from 'node-fetch';
global.fetch = nodeFetch;
import apolloClient from 'apollo-client';
const { ApolloClient } = apolloClient;
import apolloInMemoryCache from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
const { InMemoryCache } = apolloInMemoryCache;
import apolloHttpLink from 'apollo-link-http';
const { HttpLink } = apolloHttpLink;

  const cache = new InMemoryCache();
  const link = new HttpLink({
    uri
  });

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link
  });
```

That's not very nice. So there are two paths from here:

1. Switch from experimental modules to `esm` loading mechanism which doesn't encourage ecosystem to switch to native node ESM from CommonJS.
2. Create an pull request in Apollo repo and all its dependencies to put `"type": "module"` and put esm entry point to `"main"` in the `package.json` as a breaking change. Work with maintainers to support temporary compatibility and migration paths. Fork modules and maintain ESM native versions in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

We can pass `fetch` as option for HttpLink and remove `global.fetch`, here is a full exmaple:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import apolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import apolloInMemoryCache from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import apolloHttpLink from 'apollo-link-http';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const { ApolloClient } = apolloClient;
const { InMemoryCache } = apolloInMemoryCache;
const { HttpLink } = apolloHttpLink;

const uri = 'https://countries.trevorblades.com/';

const link = new HttpLink({ uri, fetch });
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const client = new ApolloClient({ link, cache });

const query = gql`
  query {
    countries {
      name
    }
  }
`;

client
  .query({ query })
  .then((result) => console.log(result.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work just using the `@apollo/client` package. You may not need the `HttpLink` and `fetch` stuff - I added that because I was getting this error: [fetch error](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/errors/#%7B%22version%22%3A%223.8.4%22%2C%22message%22%3A35%2C%22args%22%3A%5B%5D%7D).

```js
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client/index.js";
import { ApolloClient } from "@apollo/client/core/ApolloClient.js";
import { InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client/cache/inmemory/inMemoryCache.js";
import { HttpLink } from "@apollo/client/link/http/HttpLink.js";
import fetch from "cross-fetch";

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({ uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql", fetch }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```