# Shopify app with GraphQL failed to work when developing on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, graphql, shopify, apollo-client

I'm developing a Shopify private app with Node.js and React and using GraphQL api to make requests. Everything works fine when I run it locally and publish it with NGROK, but when I push the codes to Heroku, errors occur. It seems that there's something wrong with ApolloClient, but I can't figure it out.

I set up ApolloClient like this (based on this tutorial https://developers.shopify.com/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/fetch-data-with-apollo):

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

const client = new ApolloClient({
    fetchOptions: {
        credentials: 'include'
    }
});
```

When building, an error about `fetch` occurs so I modified the code (based on [Using ApolloClient with node.js. "fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688998/using-apolloclient-with-node-js-fetch-is-not-found-globally-and-no-fetcher-pas)):

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { fetch } from 'node-fetch'

const client = new ApolloClient({
    fetch: fetch,
    fetchOptions: {
        credentials: 'include'
    }
});
```

The build succeed, but my GraphQL call returns error `graphql error only absolute urls are supported`, so I tried to modified the code like this:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { fetch } from 'node-fetch'

const client = new ApolloClient({
    fetch: fetch,
    fetchOptions: {
        credentials: 'include'
    },
    uri: `https://${shopOrigin}/admin/api/2019-10/graphql.json`
});
```

The error now occurs to be `Network Error: Failed to Fetch` with a CORS issue.

Could anyone help me resolved the problem? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Issue fixed! I reset the code and tried it again today, only updated modules and added `fetch: fetch`, then it works fine this time, not sure what's the problem last week.

Answer (score 0):

The Shopify tutorial suggests using isomorphic-fetch for the server side. I tried including it in the Next.js side and the build went successful.

In my _app.js

```
require('isomorphic-fetch');
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

...

const client = new ApolloClient({
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: 'include'
  },
});
```